# Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugManifest' facebook Login

Tags: android, facebook

I am trying to integrate Facebook Login in my android app,but getting the error above,when trying to add  compile `'com.facebook.android:facebook-login:[4,5)'` in dependencies.

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugManifest'.
>   Manifest merger failed : Attribute meta-data#android.support.VERSION@value value=(25.3.1) from [com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.3.1] AndroidManifest.xml:24:9-31
>       is also present at [com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.0-alpha1] AndroidManifest.xml:27:9-38 value=(26.0.0-alpha1).
>       Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:value"' to  element at AndroidManifest.xml:22:5-24:34 to override.

[image]

Any solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your module's `build.gradle` file, put next lines:

```
configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy.eachDependency { DependencyResolveDetails details ->
        def requested = details.requested
        if (requested.group == 'com.android.support') {
            if (!requested.name.startsWith("multidex")) {
                details.useVersion '26.0.0-alpha1'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This should force all your dependencies from support library to use version `26.0.0-alpha1`

Answer (score 0):

Following block of code was repeated while integrating Facebook login, it was their from Account Kit integration. Removing one of them has resolved issue

```
<meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId"
            android:value="@string/facebook_app_id"/>
```